# Laravel 4 Form Label

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm looking to add a blank titled label field to a laravel form. However when I leave the "title" field blank and chose a "for" input it automatically assigns this to the label title.

```
{{ Form::label('name', '', array('class' => 'label-input', 'id' => 'name'))  }}
```

I've tried leaving the field blank and null, but it automatically fetches the "for" label. This is the output:

```
<label for="Name" class="label-input" id="name">Name</label>
```

Thank you in advance,

Dan

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a custom [macro](http://laravel.com/docs/html#custom-macros), like

```
Form::macro('emptyLabel', function($name, $options = array())
{
    $options = Html::attributes($options);
    return '<label for="'.$name.'"'.$options.'></label>';
});
```

Use it as

```
{{ Form::emptyLabel('name', array('class' => 'label-input', 'id' => 'name')) }}
```

Output will be

```
<label for="name" class="label-input" id="name"></label>
```

You may add the macro in your `app/start/`global or filtes, even in routes.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest possible solution

```
{{ Form::open() }}
    {{ Form::label('name', '&nbsp;') }}
    {{ Form::text('name') }
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: This will keep the element block and disrupt flow of the page. It also doesn't have text for screen readers which is part of what labels are good for.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how twitter bootstrap does this. I think it is a nice solution. If you are using bootstrap in your project just ad the .sr-only class to the label. Otherwise add the css to your own file and it should work. It is a good practice to include the label text for screen readers anyway. sr-only stands for screen reader only!

Here is the code that they are using for this class:

```
.sr-only {
   position: absolute;
   width: 1px;
   height: 1px;
   padding: 0;
   margin: -1px;
   overflow: hidden;
   clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
   border: 0
 }
```